# Why is code first migrations changing table name?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-5, ef-code-first

I am trying to make a forein key relation (one ---to----many)

And have the applicationUser have a foreinKey to an existing person table.

my code.

```
public class ApplicationUser : IdentityUser
{

    [Required]
    public long PersonId { get; set; }

    //[Required]
    [ForeignKey("PersonId")]
    public virtual Person Person { get; set; }

    public async Task<ClaimsIdentity> GenerateUserIdentityAsync(UserManager<ApplicationUser> manager)
    {
        // Note the authenticationType must match the one defined in CookieAuthenticationOptions.AuthenticationType
        var userIdentity = await manager.CreateIdentityAsync(this, DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ApplicationCookie);
        // Add custom user claims here
        return userIdentity;
    }
}
```

**Person Table(existing in db)**

```
public class Person
{
    [System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.KeyAttribute()]
    [System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.Schema.DatabaseGe‌​nerated(System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.Schema.DatabaseGen‌​eratedOption.None)]
    public long PersonId { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<ApplicationUser> Users { get; set; }
}
```

**Problem**:

When using the migrations I get the following.

**up method:**

```
        CreateTable(
            "dbo.People",
            c => new
                {
                    PersonId = c.Long(nullable: false),
                })
            .PrimaryKey(t => t.PersonId);
```

**down method:**

```
    public override void Down()
    {
        DropForeignKey("dbo.AspNetUsers", "PersonId", "dbo.People");
        DropIndex("dbo.AspNetUsers", new[] { "PersonId" });

        DropTable("dbo.People");

    }
```

Where did the dbo.People come from??? it is suppose to go to db.Person which is an already created table(via sql).

How can I solve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default Entity Framework pluralizes the entity name to name the DB table. You can switch off this behavior in the `OnModelCreating` method by adding the following code:

```
modelBuilder.Conventions.Remove<PluralizingTableNameConvention>();
```

Comment: Thank you @Alexey Andrushkevich